# String concatenation in c spread in two lines

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate two string to use in for a stat function, but when I strcat the char* and then print it shows over two lines like so.

```
./
boot
tmp
./
tmp
lib
./
lib
lost+found
./
lost+found
sbin
./
sbin
etc
```

I have tried a few things but i am probably going about this all wrong. Here is my code.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int printDetails(char *path, char *name){
 struct stat fileInfo;
 char file[100];
 strcpy(file, path);
 strcat(file, name);

 printf("%s\n", file);

 return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 struct dirent *direntp;
 DIR *dirp;

 printf("Please Enter directory path\n");
 char data[64];

 if (fgets(data, sizeof data, stdin)) {

   if ((dirp = opendir("/")) == NULL) {
      perror ("Failed to open directory");
      return 1;
   }   

   while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
   {
      printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
      if(direntp->d_name != "." && direntp->d_name != ".."){
        printDetails(data, direntp->d_name);
      }
   }

   while ((closedir(dirp) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) ;
 }
   return 0;
}
```

Any help on this issue would be great.

Thanks very much

Comment: `direntp->d_name != "." && direntp->d_name != ".."` is pointer comparison, not string comparison. Use `strcmp` in order to compare the pointed data (i.e., the contents of the strings up to a null-character).

Comment: @barakmanos thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` will include the `\n` character at the end of each line. That is, assuming the line of text isn't longer than the size you pass in - otherwise you'll get only part of the line.

Comment: using `fgets` is fine - you just need to add in some code to remove the `\n` if it exists.

Comment: A good idiom for removing the newline is `data[strcspn(data, "\n")] = '\0';` — which works correctly whether there is a newline in the data or not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler never seen that way before, but I like it - very easy to add in stripping of `\r` too :)